# Convert json file to csv in RestApi express js

Tags: node.js, json, csv

I have the following command in the file entry.routes.js at location: /nodejs-express-mysql/app/routes

```
app.get("/energy/api/ActualvsForecast/:AreaName/:Resolution/date/:Year-:Month-:Day/format=:Type", entry.findFourteen);
```

I have also written the following code inside entry.controller.js file in location: /nodejs-express-mysql/app/controllers

```
exports.findFourteen = (req, res) => {


    Entry.findByPars13(req.params.AreaName,req.params.Resolution,req.params.Year,req.params.Month,req.params.Day,req.params.Types, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          if (err.kind === "not_found") {
            res.status(404).send({
              message: `Not found Entry with AreaName ${req.params.AreaName}. Five`
            });
          } else {
            res.status(500).send({
              message: "Error retrieving Entry with AreaName " + req.params.AreaName
            });
          }
        } else{
            if(req.params.Type=="csv"){
                 message:"This is csv and the format is: " +req.params.Type
                 res.send(data);
            }
            else if (req.params.Type=="json"){
                 message:"This is json and the format is: " +req.params.Type
                 res.send(data);
           }
          }
      });
    };
```

I would like to write some commands in the ifs for csv and json so that if the user specifies the format as csv it returns the data in csv form. The json returns as default so changes inside that if I believe should not be done. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json2csv` for ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv npm as follows:

```
json2csv({ data: yourdata, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.csv');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    res.status(200).send(csv);
  });
```

Comment: Do I need to install anything for this?

Comment: @thriteen chess  yes json2csv package `npm i json2csv --save`

Comment: and I just add this part of the code in your answer inside the if ?

Comment: @thriteen chess yes exactly

Comment: Inside fields: ... What do I write? I wrote data: data as this is my data but I don't know what I should put inside fileds

Comment: @thriteen chess specify your column names(is what json keys)

Comment: I did include the fileds like this :  fields: ("Source","Dataset","AreaName","AreaTypeCode","MapCode","ResolutionCode","Year","Month","Day") but when I run the query in Postman it says sending request for quite some time. Is the function json2csv slow? Can I print the results? Wehre does data.csv get saved?